# Create Dynamics CRM Audit Partition Programmatically

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2013

The CRM Audit Partition Job in our system is disabled. Is there a way to create a quarterly Audit Partition programmatically given a start date and an end date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if something break that job nature. Probably you have to create a ticket with MS support to get assistance on this matter.

There’s no SDK message or API request to achieve this Audit partitions.

The Audit partition is taken care in SQL Partitioning in database level and [this blog](http://tunnik.name/crm-audit-log-and-sql-partitioning/) explains an unsupported hack to do in SQL directly. Use this to understand the concept and it’s not advised to try this in CRM instance.